# CSS Background Image not showing up CSS HAML

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, background-image, haml

I have a background image url in a stylesheet that I'm trying to render for the header in my index page. The image is located in the assets/images folder. I tried putting in vendor/assets/images and it's not rendering from there either.

views/splash/index.html.haml:

```
%section.row.header-bg
  .row
    .col-md-6.col-md-offset-1
```

assets/stylesheets/splash.css.scss:

```
.header-bg{
    background-image: url('bg.png');
}
```

EDIT: I tried every variation I could think of for the image URL but no luck so far.

Comment: Try inspecting the element in the rendered HTML with dev tools. You can see if the rule is getting applied and if it's being overridden by something or if the image can't be found

Comment: @redbmk I get a 404 not found error. The url is looking at images/bg.png

Comment: Have you tried changing the image to use an absolute path? e.g. `background-image: url('/assets/images/bg.png');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Correct CSS:

```
.header-bg{
  background: image-url('bg.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please try like this it will work :**

background-image: image-url('bg.png');

Comment: That didn't work. Inspect element is showing that it renders a text/hml type.

Comment: What do you mean? @user3462905

Comment: I think you just change the css property background-image to background that is not your problem and your main problem is image path that was not correct .

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:   Hope this can help you!

```
background-image: url('images/bg.png');

or
background-image: url('assets/images/bg.png');
```

Comment: Try doing: background-image: url('.../assets/images/bg.png');

Comment: or background-image: url('/assets/images/bg.png');

Comment: I still get ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/bg.png")

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're targeting your css folder for the image. 
Assuming your images and stylesheets folder is conatained within your vendor/assets folder - You will need to navigate up one level.

try prefixing url with ../

```
background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
```